# Google+ this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key showCircleCount

Tags: ios, google-plus, share

I am using Google+ native sharing in my app.But its not working , i had tried the below code .

```
if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {

        id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
        [shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"karthi!"];
        [(id<GPPNativeShareBuilder>)shareBuilder attachImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off-1.png"]];
        [shareBuilder open];
    }
    else
    {
        self.signInButton.hidden = NO;

    }
```

Here i am getting the exception like this ,

**Unknown class GPPNativeShareACLViewController in Interface Builder file.**

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key showCircleCount.'**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean? "'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ... This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check your Header Path in Build Setting of your project, that might have not set correctly. You can delete sdk and add again so that project take its path again